# $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ acting on extended complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, linear-groups

> Let $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ the general linear group of order two on complex. We can define a action from $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{C}^*$ as
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}{a}&{b}\\{c}&{d}\end{bmatrix}\cdot z=\displaystyle\frac{az+b}{cz+d} $$
>   prove that there exist only one orbit i.e for every $z\in \mathbb{C}^*$ we have $L_2(\mathbb{C})z=\mathbb{C}$.

I'd appreciate a hint to solve this problem. I think that for a given $z,w\in \mathbb{C}^*$ I should find a matrix $A\in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A\cdot z =w$ but I don't know how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exactly the right idea!  The only question left is how one finds such a transformation.

**Hint:** If $z \neq 0$, we can always find a suitable transformation with $b = c = 0$

Comment: A rotation and an expansion. Thanks!